# Issues retrieving a value to use for comparaison in an if statement

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following variable:

```
   var userFound = false;
```

In the event this turns true, I would like the below if statement to be executed:

```
 if (userFound) {
    //
        res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});

  }
```

However, the issue is that it does not take into account the value change of the variable inside of a for loop above. Below is larger portion of the code.

```
var userFound = false;

let sql = `SELECT box_id, cubby_id, comport, deliveredToUser
                   FROM recipients
                   WHERE package_password = ?`;

connection.query(sql, [req.session.sessionUserPackagePassword], function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      // Make the comparaison case insensitive

      if ((rows[i].deliveredToUser).toLowerCase() == `no`) {
        userFound = true;



        var comport = rows[i].comport;
        var command = "open" + rows[i].cubby_id;
        var commandClose = "close" + rows[i].cubby_id;
        var commandStatus = "status" + rows[i].cubby_id;



        console.log(command);
        console.log(comport);


        var options = {
          scriptPath: 'python/scripts',
          args: [command, comport, commandClose, commandStatus] // pass arguments to the script here

        };


        PythonShell.run('controlLock.py', options, function(err, results) {
          if (err) {
            res.render('errorConnection', {});
          }
          console.log('results: %j', results);
        });

      }



    }

    // If the query fails to execute
  } else {
    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    res.render('errorConnection', {});

  }
});
connection.end();

if (userFound) {
  //
  res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could simply move `res.render()` to the line where you set `userFound = true`.

Comment: It's actually the oposite if tthere is no instance that matches this                                  if ((rows[i].deliveredToUser).toLowerCase() == `no`) {
 thats where i want to render this page             res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});
  the issue when i put the else if condition inside the for loop is that it doesnt go through all of the for loop row before running the page

Comment: I see. You can let the for-loop fully traverse and move the if-test (`if (userFound)`) directly after the for-loop.

Comment: Even when (if (userFound))  is moved right after the for loop it doesnt seem to record the update value in userFound which is now true so it assumes it false. Hence, when no condition is satisfied this if statement is not executed

Comment: It seems like any value set inside of the for loop stays inside of the for loop

Comment: any advice anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback where you set userFound to true is run after the if (userFound) line runs, even though they are not written in that order. connection.query is an async function. Try putting the userFound logic inside the callback so that it runs after the query result is received and userFound is set to true.

```
connection.query(sql, [req.session.sessionUserPackagePassword], function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      // Make the comparaison case insensitive

      if ((rows[i].deliveredToUser).toLowerCase() == `no`) {
        userFound = true;

        var comport = rows[i].comport;
        var command = "open" + rows[i].cubby_id;
        var commandClose = "close" + rows[i].cubby_id;
        var commandStatus = "status" + rows[i].cubby_id;

        console.log(command);
        console.log(comport);

        var options = {
          scriptPath: 'python/scripts',
          args: [command, comport, commandClose, commandStatus] // pass arguments to the script here

        };


        PythonShell.run('controlLock.py', options, function(err, results) {
          if (err) {
            res.render('errorConnection', {});
          }
          console.log('results: %j', results);
        });

      }
    }

    // If the query fails to execute
  } else {
    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    res.render('errorConnection', {});
  }
  connection.end();

  if (userFound) {
    //
    res.render('pickup/errorAlreadyDelivered', {});

  }
});
```